# TightVNC Server not allowing to use -connect and -sharedisplay arguments together

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, vnc, tightvnc

I am unable to use TightVNC in reverse connection mode sharing a specified window, display region or secondary monitor.

This is how I set VNCViewer to listen:

```
tvnviewer.exe -listen
```

At this point I am unable to set it to listen on any other port than 5500, even with the `-port` argument, but whatever, it's a matter for another post.

This works well:

```
tvnserver.exe -controlservice -connect 192.168.25.104:5500
```

However any of the following don't:

```
tvnserver.exe -controlservice -connect 192.168.25.104:5500 -sharedisplay 2
tvnserver.exe -controlservice -connect 192.168.25.104:5500 -sharerect 100x100+0+0
tvnserver.exe -controlservice -sharedisplay 2 -connect 192.168.25.104:5500
tvnserver.exe -controlservice -sharerect 100x100+0+0 -connect 192.168.25.104:5500
```

An interesting note is that if I run the following (notice the mistake on the rectangle definition):

```
tvnserver.exe -controlservice -sharerect 100x100++0 -connect 192.168.25.104:5500
```

an alert is shown saying that this is not a valid rectangle, so it looks like it understood every argument, but it just doesn't know how to execute with the two arguments set at the same time, which is pretty weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it; TVNC accepts only one argument at once. This is the way I must do:

```
tvnserver.exe -controlservice -sharedisplay 2
tvnserver.exe -controlservice -connect 192...
```